# Strange BaseAdapter behaviour when an item is clicked

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have a GridView with a certain number of pictures. When a picture is clicked, a new activity starts which displays it fullscreen. Now the weird thing that happens is :

When you click on the first picture (index 0), it doesn't start the activity as it should. For the rest of my pictures it is doing it fine. But when i click on the first item and then i click on another item, the first item pops up (index 0) with the correct tapped item beneath it. It is also very annoying that when i tap the close button when this strange behaviour is appearing, the first item (index 0) restarts itself a numerous number of times. 
Now my Adapter code is as follows :

```
class GridAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    private Context c;
    private List<string[]> griditems;
    private int ColumnWidth;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private App app;

    public GridAdapter(Context c, List<string[]> griditems, int ColumnWidth) {
        this.c = c;
        this.griditems = griditems;
        this.ColumnWidth = ColumnWidth;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.From (c);
        app = (App)Application.Context;
    }

    #region implemented abstract members of BaseAdapter

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem (int position)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }

    public override long GetItemId (int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        ImageView ImageView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.PhotoGridItem, parent, false);
            ImageView = (ImageView)convertView.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.Photo);

        } else {

            ImageView = (ImageView)convertView.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.Photo);

        }

        ImageView.SetScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);

        convertView.LayoutParameters = new GridView.LayoutParams (ColumnWidth, ColumnWidth);
        ImageView.LayoutParameters = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (ColumnWidth , ColumnWidth);

        convertView.Click  += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {

            var intent = new Intent (Application.Context, typeof(PhotoActivity));
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            intent.PutExtra("position", position);
            Application.Context.StartActivity (intent);

        };

        UrlImageViewHelper.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable (ImageView, griditems.ElementAt(position)[1], Resource.Drawable.no_location);



        return convertView;

    }

    public override int Count {
        get {
            return this.griditems.Count;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public void Append(List<string[]> items) {
        this.griditems.Concat (items);
    }

    public void Prepend(List<string[]> items) {
        items.Reverse ();
        items.Concat (this.griditems);
    }

    public void Replace(List<string[]> items) {
        this.griditems.Clear ();
        items.Reverse();
        this.griditems = items;
    }
```

And the activity that it starts is as follows :

```
public class PhotoActivity : Activity
{
    private ViewPager ViewPager;
    private PhotoAdapter Adapter;
    private App app;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        app = (App)Application.Context;
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.PhotoActivity);

        ViewPager = (ViewPager)FindViewById<ViewPager> (Resource.Id.pager);

        Intent i = Intent;
        int position = i.GetIntExtra ("position", 0);

        Adapter = new PhotoAdapter (this, app.PhotoList);

        ViewPager.Adapter = Adapter;

        ViewPager.CurrentItem = position;
    }

    protected override void OnDestroy ()
    {
        ViewPager.Dispose ();
        Adapter.Dispose ();
        base.OnDestroy ();
        Console.WriteLine ("OnDestroy () called");
    }
}
```

Does anybody knows what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I would heavily recommend taking the Click event out of the adapter. When using GridViews or ListViews, you want to use the ItemClick event on the GridView or override your OnListItemClick method of your custom ListActivity..

When using a ListActivity, you can use the code that is on the bottom, adapted to something like what you need.

A partner of mine has a blog post on how to integrate Context menu's into a ListActivity.  You might want to look at that post.  Typically use cases start out with a single action involving a click on an item, but potentially, you may end up wanting to have a menu of options for any click.. Here is a link.

If you want to close your ListActivity or the Activity that has your GridView in it after starting your new activity.. simply add this.Finish() to the bottom of either code example below.

[Context Menu Blog Post](http://slackshotindustries.blogspot.com/search/label/ContextMenu)

Oh, and um... Welcome to Xamarin.

```
gridview.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, ItemEventArgs args) {
        var intent = new Intent (Application.Context, typeof(PhotoActivity));
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        intent.PutExtra("position", args.Position);
        this.StartActivity (intent);
};

protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
        var intent = new Intent (Application.Context,typeof(PhotoActivity));
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            intent.PutExtra("position", position);
            this.StartActivity (intent);
}
```

Comment: I agree here. The `Adapter` should only take care of presenting data, interaction with the data should not be in the `Adapter`. This means you can use the `Adapter` elsewhere without having to rely on its hardcoded click events. So as Slack Shot says, use the `ItemClick` event, however it seems like you are using a `ViewPager` and not a `GridView` like you described, which means what you actually are doing is the correct thing, with having the `Click` handler inside the `Adapter`, because the `ViewPager` does not expose something similar. `ViewPager` is meant for an entirely different use case